# Mysql count, join, and dual in conjunction

Tags: mysql, join, count

I have a table tester which has a primary id and a foreign key that references the id of a table called test.

The test table has a column numAllowed that indicates how many people can take this particular test.

I want to insert a new tester whose test column references a test only if there are less testers that also reference the same test than numAllowed for that particular test. Ex, "Alex", a tester, can only take the test "Geography" if less than 20 people (numAllowed) are taking/have taken it already.

Also, how does the count function operate in a query like this? Does it only count the columns that are included in the joins or is its "scope" outside the query? will it return the count of all ids in that table?

```
   insert into tester (test, createddate, ipaddress) 
   select 
      11, NOW(), xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 
   from 
      dual 
   where exists 
   ( select * from 
      test ts inner join 
         tester tr 
      on tr.test = ts.id 
      where ts.numAllowed - count(tr.id) > 0 
      and ts.id = '11')
```

Comment: what do you have in your `dual` table?

Comment: Nothing, it's for selecting your own values as far as i know.

Comment: Don't know if dual is supported by mySQL, but i am pretty sure you cannot use aggregate functions like count() in WHERE clause. You need to group the data and use a HAVING clause.

Comment: Why don't you use a trigger to enforce your business rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write your query like this:

```
INSERT INTO tester (test, createddate, ipaddress) 
SELECT
  test.ID, NOW(), 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'
FROM
  test
WHERE
  test.ID = 1
  AND EXISTS (SELECT COUNT(*)
              FROM tester
              WHERE tester.test = test.ID
              HAVING test.numAllowed-COUNT(*)>0);
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b258e/1).